# Are the library location on Android 4.2.1 moved?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, libraries, shared-libraries

I faced a suspicious problem when I tried to update my Android App to work on 4.2.1, Nexus 7. I'm using my own .so library, which inclusion was working fine on Android version 4.1, before I updated. Now I get all sorts of problems.

I compared the logs when deploying on an Android device running 3.2.1 and my Nexus 7 running 4.2.1. The library is being placed in two different locations, which might be causing my problems.

ANDROID 3.2.1:

```
Trying to load lib /data/data/com.my.app/lib/lib_my_app_jni.so 0x407e8218
Added shared lib /data/data/com.my.app/lib/lib_my_app_jni.so 0x407e8218
```

ANDROID 4.2.1 (Nexus 7):

```
Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.my.app-1/lib_my_app_api_jni.so 0x4257b6c8
Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.my.app-1/lib_my_app_api_jni.so 0x4257b6c8
```

Why is it all of the sudden placed in the mysteries app-lib dir? How do I force it back? And where is this documented?

Thanks...

Comment: What sort of "problems" are you seeing? The location of the library shouldn't be an issue, unless you hardcoded paths for some inexplicable reason.

Comment: I'm copying in other stuff that the library uses, extern certificates, etc. Is there any way to force the library to be loaded into /data/data/ instaed of /data/app-lib/ like in the old Android versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question, because we ended up implementing our library differently then originally intended.

The problem was that we were copying over access certificates and more, to the directory that the library was in. This approach worked fine on older Android versions, where that was located in the data/data/package/. But on newer Android versions (data/app-lib/package/) that location is read-only.

What we did was to move the location, simple. Thanks for the input.

Comment: while this solves your problem, please consider changing you accept to the answer which is actually an answer to the question you posted.

Answer (score 6):

From Android 4.2, multi-user feature added in android frameworks.

And several directory locations are changed, but API is not changed such as Context.get???Dir() or Context.get???Path(). (just return value is changed)

Also android platform make symbolic link for legacy.

These changes are not documented.

Comment: I found a little documentation about the subject [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#MultipleUsers). Is it correct that you have read/write access to _/data/data/com.my.app/_, but only read access to _/data/app-lib/com.my.app-1/_. That would cause problems for me.

Comment: @MartinR - I don't believe apps have ever had write access to their lib directory even when it was under their private directory, or at least not for many Android versions now.  The packager extracts libraries there, but the app cannot.  You can however extract a library elsewhere in your private storage, mark it executable, and load it with System.load() and an actual path name rather than System.loadLibrary() and the truncated lib name.